# Proof Verification for Almost Uniform Convergence implies Convergence in Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I shall attach my proof for the statement "Almost Uniform Convergence Imply Convergence in Measure" here. I know this is a lot longer than what it is necessary to be, but I want everything in the proof to be crystal clear to me. I also bolded the part that I am unsure about:

Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be the measure space. Suppose $f_n \xrightarrow{a.u.} f$. That is, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $E_\epsilon \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu(E_\epsilon) < \epsilon$ and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in X - E_\epsilon}|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0.
$$
We wish to show for all $c > 0$ that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq c \}) = 0.
$$
To this end, for all $c > 0$ and $n \in \mathbf{N}$, we define $A_c^n = \{ x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq c \}$. Then for all $c > 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we must have $A_c^n \cap (X - E_\epsilon) = \emptyset$ for $n$ large enough.
To see this, let $\epsilon > 0$. Then we must have some $E_\epsilon \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu(E_\epsilon) < \epsilon$ and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in X - E_\epsilon} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0.
$$
Therefore, for all $a > 0$, there exists $N(a, \epsilon) \in \mathbf{N}$ such that if $n \geq N(a, \epsilon)$, then
$$
\sup_{x \in X - E_\epsilon} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < a.
$$
Thus we must have if $n \geq N(a, \epsilon)$, then for all $x \in X - E_\epsilon$ that
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in X - E_\epsilon} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < a.
$$
In particular, for all $c > 0$, there exists $N(c, \epsilon) \in \mathbf{N}$ such that if $n \geq N(c, \epsilon)$, then for all $x \in X - E_\epsilon$ that $$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| < c.
$$
Thus for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $c > 0$, there exists $N(c, \epsilon) \in \mathbf{N}$ such that if $n \geq N(c, \epsilon)$, then $x \not \in A_c^n$. In particular, this implies for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $c > 0$, there exists $N(c, \epsilon) \in \mathbf{N}$ such that if $n \geq N(c, \epsilon)$, then $A_c^n \subseteq E_\epsilon$. **Therefore, we have for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $c > 0$, there exists $N(\epsilon, c) \in \mathbf{N}$ such that if $n \geq N(\epsilon, c)$, then
$$
\mu(A_c^n) \leq \mu(E_\epsilon) < \epsilon.
$$
Thus, we have for all $c > 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$ that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_c^n) \leq \epsilon.
$$**
Thus we have for all $c > 0$ that
$$
0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_c^n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq c \}) \leq 0.
$$
In particular, we must have for all $c > 0$ that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{ x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq c \}) = 0.
$$
This proves that $f_n \xrightarrow{\mu} f$ by definition.

My Question:

Is the part that I marked above correct? I am unsure because our $N$ is dependent on $\epsilon > 0$. However, since $\epsilon$ is fixed and given, I think the inequality should be fine by, for example, this result: [Comparison for Sequences](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/comparison-theorems-for-sequences). How about other parts of the proof? Is the proof correct?

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the part you felt most uncomfortable about. Note that I still expect users to read the complete proof, but it allows others to know where to focus. +1, this is the perfect solution-verification (I don't think it is a duplicate either) and I hope this gets a befitting answer.

Comment: Instead of your conclusion,  you can only conclude that $\limsup_n \mu(A_c^n) \leq \varepsilon$. You don't even need to do this though. You are already done at this point since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary.